# How do your add multiple plugins to cypress/plugins/index.js file?

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

My cypress/plugins/index.js file looks like this and I know that there can only be one module.exports, but I'm struggling to add cypressBrowserPermissionsPlugin and getConfigurationByFile together

```
const cucumber = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default
const { cypressBrowserPermissionsPlugin } = require('cypress-browser-permissions')
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')
require('@applitools/eyes-cypress')(module);

function getConfigurationByFile(file) {
  const pathToConfigFile = path.resolve('cypress/config', `${file}.json`);
  return fs.readJson(pathToConfigFile);
}
const file = config.env.configFile || 'qa';

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('file:preprocessor', cucumber())
  config = cypressBrowserPermissionsPlugin(on, config)
  return config
  // I want to also return the getConfigurationByFile(file) function
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to wrap the function `getConfigurationByFile` into a [task](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task.html)

```
function getConfigurationByFile(file) {
  const pathToConfigFile = path.resolve('cypress/config', `${file}.json`);
  return fs.readJson(pathToConfigFile);
}

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('file:preprocessor', cucumber());
  on('task', {
    getConfiguration (fileName) {
      const file = fileName || config.env.configFile || 'qa'; // filename defaults
      return getConfigurationByFile (file);
    }
  })
  config = cypressBrowserPermissionsPlugin(on, config);
  return config;
}
```

and call it in the test like this

```
cy.task('getConfiguration', 'my-config-file').then(config => {
   ...
});
```

or with default file name

```
cy.task('getConfiguration').then(config => {
   ...
});
```